# Jetta Part Identification

Tags: vw, part-identification, parts, jetta

I just bought a 2013 VW Jetta SE with a 5-speed manual trans. I'm new to Volkswagen, and I found this part in my glovebox. Does anyone know what it could be?

[image]

Comment: Any pictures of the front or is it blank?

Comment: I can't place it.  I have a 2011 Jetta, and I've never seen it (NOT a definative answer).  My guess it that a detail guy found it when cleaning and put in in the glovebox just in case it was related to the car.  I'll give it a 50/50 shot of actually being a part of the car.

Comment: Does it have any numbers stamped onto it?  Most VW parts, even little pieces of plastic trim, typically have part numbers stamped or cast into them.

Comment: Showing it from multiple angles could help.  As @SteveMatthews stated, look for numbers on the component to post in here.

Comment: Between the "clips" there are raised numbers. POM 15

Comment: Could you add dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

I used to own a VW and it looks like a switch cover like for flashers,heater, etc.